# Is $PSL(2,13)$ a chief factor of the automorphism group of a $\{2,3\}$-group?

Tags: gr.group-theory, finite-groups

Does there exists a group $H$ of order $2^7\cdot 3^4$, such that $\mathrm{PSL}(2, 13)$ is a chief factor of $\mathrm{Aut}(H)$?

Comment: Did you check the cyclic group of that order?

Comment: @zibadawa timmy.     If $H$ is cyclic, then $|\mathrm{Aut}(H)|=2^7\cdot3^3$.

Comment: @Qin You're missing the point.  When $H$ is cyclic, what's $\operatorname{Aut}(H)$?  Is it, perhaps, abelian? Your question is either missing assumptions and/or has errors, or you've failed to check the easiest possible case.

Comment: @zibadawa When $H$ is cyclic, we know $|\mathrm{Aut}(H)|=2^7\cdot3^3$. By $|PSL(2,13)|=2^2\cdot2\cdot7\cdot13$, the answer is "No".

Comment: @Qin Moreover, the automorphism group of a finite cyclic group is abelian.

Comment: The use of "a" is, once more, ambiguous. You should reformulate the question as: does there exist $H$ of order ... such that...

Comment: @DerekHolt  Can you give me a detail proof?  Thank you.

Answer (score 9):

Here is a sketch of a proof that the answer is no.

*Lemma* If $N$ is an elementary abelian normal subgroup of a group $G$, then the subgroup of ${\rm Aut}(G)$ consiting of automorphisms that fix $N$ and induce the indentity on $N$ and $G/N$ is an elementary abelian $p$-group. (It is actually the group $Z^1(G/N,N)$ of $1$-cocycles of $G/N$ on $N$.)

*Corollary* If $1=N_0 < N_1 < N_2 < \cdots N_k =G$ with all $N_i \lhd G$ and each $N_{i+1}/N_i$ elementary abelian, then the subgroup of ${\rm Aut}(G)$ of automorphisms inducing the identity on all $N_{i+1}/N_i$ is solvable.

Now any group $G$ of order $2^7 \times 3^4$ is solvable and hence has a sequence of characteristic subgroups $1=N_0 < N_1 < N_2 < \cdots N_k =G$ with each $N_{i+1}/N_i$ elementary abelian.

By the corollary above, if ${\rm PSL}(2,13)$ occurs as a chief factor of ${\rm Aut}(G)$, then it must be a chief factor of a subgroup of ${\rm Aut}(N_{i+1}/N_i)$ for some $i$, and ${\rm Aut}(N_{i+1}/N_i) \cong {\rm PSL}(k,2)$ for some $k \le 7$ or ${\rm PSL}(k,3)$ for some $k \le 4$.

But, you can check easily that  ${\rm GL}(7,2)$ does not have order divisible by $13$, and  ${\rm GL}(4,3)$ does not have order divisible by $7$, whereas  $13$ and $7$ both divide $|{\rm PSL}(2,13)|$, so this cannot happen.

Comment: This proof is every interesting.    Could you tell me the titles of some papers or books about this Lemma?  I want to see the proof of Lemma and Corollary. Thank you every much. @Derek Holt

Comment: The proofs are straightforward. Try and prove them yourself.

Comment: @GeoffRobinson Yes, well spotted! But luckily it doesn't have order divisible by $7$.

Comment: Is every non-abelian composition factor of $H$ isomorphic to $PSL(k,2)$ for some $k\leq7$ or $PSL(k,3)$ for some $k\leq4$ by using this method? @Derek Holt

Comment: I haven't thought about that. A statement like that would not be true in general for larger $k$. What I said was that every nonabelian chief (and hence also composition) factor of $H$ is isomorphic to a composition factor of a subgroup of ${\rm GL}(k,2)$  or ${\rm GL}(k,3)$ for $k$ with the range.

Comment: The answer is no. One of the two types of extraspecial groups of order $2^7$ has automorphism group with a composition factor isomorphic to $O^-_6(2) \cong U_4(2) \cong S_4(3)$.

Comment: Suppose $|H|=2^6\cdot 3^6$. By using this method,  is $PSL(11,2)$ a chief factor of Aut(H)?  I consider the prime number $11$,  and $11\nmid |GL(k,2)|$ for $k<10$, $11\big| |GL(k,3)|$ for $k>4$. Then I don't have any idea about this problem. Can you give me some suggestions?  @Derek Holt

Comment: I think you mean ${\rm PSL}(2,11)$. It has irreducible modules of dimension $5$ over the field of order $3$ (and also ${\rm SL}(2,11)$ has modules of dimension $6$), so yes this can happen.